# How to use trigger to make changes in table when the specified date arrives in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have a database for documents and it has a column to indicate if the document is archived or not. The document will be set to archive after a month has passed when the document is received. Here is the create statement of the document table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dts_document` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `subject` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `description` text,
   `action` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `from` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `deadline` date NOT NULL,
   `attachment` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
   `status` enum('Compiled','On-Going','Cancelled','') DEFAULT NULL,
   `referenceNumber` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `dateReceived` date NOT NULL,
   `archive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;
```

The "dateReceived" is when the document is added to the database. Now "archived" is set to '0' at default to indicate that it is not yet in the archives. When a month has passed since the document is received it should automatically be set to '1' to indicate that it is now in the archives.

How can this be done? Can it be done with triggers? As I have read triggers are 'triggered' on insert, update or delete. Is there any other way?

Need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger on an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement to a table or view (DML Trigger)

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ schema_name . ]trigger_name 
ON { table | view } 
[ WITH <dml_trigger_option> [ ,...n ] ]
{ FOR | AFTER | INSTEAD OF } 
{ [ INSERT ] [ , ] [ UPDATE ] [ , ] [ DELETE ] } 
[ WITH APPEND ]
[ NOT FOR REPLICATION ] 
AS { sql_statement  [ ; ] [ ,...n ] | EXTERNA`z`L NAME <method specifier           [ ; ] > }

<dml_trigger_option> ::=
[ ENCRYPTION ]
[ EXECUTE AS Clause ]

<method_specifier> ::= 
assembly_name.class_name.method_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the [MySQL scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) for this. You can set up an event to repeat once per day, and in this - simply archive all documents older than one month.

```
create event archive_documents
  on schedule
    every 1 day
    starts '2015-05-09 01:00:00' on completion preserve enable
  do
    update dts_document 
      set archive = 1
      where datereceived < now() - interval 1 month;
```

in order for this to work you would need to make sure the global variable `event_scheduler` is set to on.